# Unable to pass dictionary to function in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, fuzzy-search

I am trying to match a word to a list index (stored in csv) I have using fuzzy matching. I load the index into a dictionary. Then create a function to compare two strings as given. If the ratio matched is larger than the threshold, then return the index and indexed string.

This is what I have tried.

```
def fuzzy_token_set_matching(index_dict, str_for_comparison):
    matching_threshold = 70 

    #If I try to get dict size here, it's 0
    print(len(index_dict))     

    for index, indexed_string in index_dict.items():       
        max_ratio = 0
        #Compare two string using fuzzy matching
        fuzz_matching_ratio = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(indexed string, str_for_comparison)        
        if fuzz_matching_ratio > max_ratio:
            max_ratio = fuzz_matching_ratio            

            if max_ratio > matching_threshold:
                return index_index, title                
            else:
                return None

input_file = 'index.csv'
output_file = 'results.csv'

#Load index list into a dictionary
with open(input_file, mode = 'r') as index_infile:
    index_reader = csv.reader(index_infile)
    index_dict = {rows[0]:rows[2] for rows in index_reader}

print(fuzz.token_sort_ratio(index_dict, 'test'))

>>> Results return: 0
```

I am getting 0 even though I have an exact match which should give me matching ratio of 100. For some reasons I am unable to pass the dictionary to the function.

Comment: What exactly does your CSV file contain? Your problem is related to reading the CSV file, not to passing the dictionary to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are calling the wrong function. `fuzz.token_sort_ratio(index_dict, 'test')` is not `fuzzy_token_set_matching(index_dict, str_for_comparison)`.

So you should try the following instead:

```
print(fuzzy_token_set_matchin(index_dict, 'test'))
```

Comment: I made a mistake when copy pasting the function names. Thanks